GCP Logs not capturing User Information for BQ Queries run from vertex workbench instance
GCP does the logging when the user queries via BigQuery UI. Perhaps the same querying through the workbench, it does not log user pertinent information (Owner of the instance name, nor VM/Workbench name)
Is this expected? (or) Is there a way that logs may capture the relevant information on who made the query? I know service account of the underlying compute_instance is capture. However, this is not we're looking for!
I've also assigned custom labels to the instance assuming it would atleast capture this information.
{
"protoPayload": {
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
"status": {},
"authenticationInfo": {
"principalEmail": "123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"serviceAccountDelegationInfo": [
{
"firstPartyPrincipal": {
"principalEmail": "service-123456789@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
}
]
},
"requestMetadata": {
"callerIp": "*.*.*.*",
"callerSuppliedUserAgent": "ipython-8.21.0 gl-python/3.10.14 grpc/1.62.1 gax/1.34.1 gapic/3.20.1 gccl/3.20.1,gzip(gfe)",
"callerNetwork": "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/steady-tracer-12345/global/networks/__unknown__",
"requestAttributes": {},
"destinationAttributes": {}
},
"serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
"methodName": "jobservice.getqueryresults",
"authorizationInfo": [
{
"resource": "projects/steady-tracer-12345",
"permission": "bigquery.jobs.create",
"granted": true,
"resourceAttributes": {}
},
{
"resource": "projects/steady-tracer-12345",
"permission": "bigquery.jobs.create",
"granted": true,
"resourceAttributes": {}
}
],
"resourceName": "projects/steady-tracer-12345/queries/5c37d6f7-919a-4d0c-9fe0-6ae21f25dbd5",
"serviceData": {
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData",
"jobGetQueryResultsRequest": {},
"jobGetQueryResultsResponse": {
"totalResults": "42",
"job": {
"jobName": {
"projectId": "steady-tracer-12345",
"jobId": "5c37d6f7-919a-4d0c-9fe0-6ae21f25dbd5",
"location": "US"
},
"jobConfiguration": {
"query": {
"query": "SELECT * FROM `steady-tracer-12345.test_dataset.top_words` LIMIT 1000;",
"destinationTable": {
"projectId": "steady-tracer-12345",
"datasetId": "_a3ec690a6c8f1d9369fdee628f0f7aba9bd7ce24",
"tableId": "anonc3a5f202530cb1c670058090a9e19fd45c74fd2de785f7e562bc5a2b37fa0641"
},
"createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
"writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
"defaultDataset": {},
"queryPriority": "QUERY_INTERACTIVE",
"statementType": "SELECT"
}
},
"jobStatus": {
"state": "DONE",
"error": {}
},
"jobStatistics": {
"createTime": "2024-05-05T19:10:14.011Z",
"startTime": "2024-05-05T19:10:14.161Z",
"endTime": "2024-05-05T19:10:14.243Z",
"reservation": "unreserved"
}
}
}
}
},
"insertId": "-vc7iqse2w6df",
"resource": {
"type": "bigquery_resource",
"labels": {
"project_id": "steady-tracer-12345"
}
},
"timestamp": "2024-05-05T19:10:14.465276Z",
"severity": "INFO",
"logName": "projects/steady-tracer-12345/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
"receiveTimestamp": "2024-05-05T19:10:14.816987674Z"
}


Currently the code executed from Workbench instance is using the Service Account attached to the VM (123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com).
You will need End User Credentials in Colab Enterprise.
End User Credentials in Workbench instance is also something in our roadmap.
As workaround you can use:
!gcloud auth application-default login

